# SolrCloud 7.2 with BasicAuth - IndexFetcher Http client requests are unauthenticated

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Whenever the IndexFetcher class is called for recovery or replication the HTTP requests are unauthenticated resulting in 401 errors:

> 2018-01-25 13:16:22.538 WARN  (indexFetcher-25-thread-1)
>   [c:myCollection s:shard1 r:core_node3
>   x:myCollection_shard1_replica_t1] o.a.s.h.IndexFetcher Master at:
>   http://server1:8983/solr/myCollection_shard1_replica_t4/ is not
>   available. Index fetch failed by exception:
>   org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException:
>   Error from server at
>   http://server1:8983/solr/myCollection_shard1_replica_t4: Expected mime
>   type application/octet-stream but got text/html.   
>   Error 401 Unauthorized request, Response code: 401
>
> ### HTTP ERROR 401
>
> Problem accessing
>   /solr/myCollection_shard1_replica_t4/replication. Reason:
>
> ```
> Unauthorized request, Response code: 401
> ```

I checked the source code and before creating a new HTTP client in IndexFetcher it tries to get http auth user/password from initArgs but those properties are always null, event if I set them in the replication handler (under the slave tag).

```
 <lst name="slave">

<str name="masterUrl">http://server1:port/solr/myCollection/replication</str>

 <str name="httpBasicAuthUser">username</str>

<str name="httpBasicAuthPassword">password</str>

</lst>
```

I downloaded the solr source code and entered the username and password hardcoded, compiled the jar and everything was working fine. Before this I used the logger to check the httpBasicAuthUser/httpBasicAuthPassword and whenever IndexFetcher was called for recovery or replication these fields were null.